# Is there a way of toggling elements in a python list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm new in programming, and am finding a way (if any) to toggle the elements in a list.

I have a list where the elements can be either 1 or 0. I want to toggle them went I give a particular input.
I tried the following way:

```py
i = input('Enter something: ')
check_var_list = ['1', '1', '0']
if i == 'Particular input':
    for element in check_var_list:
        if int(element) == 0:
            element = 1
        elif int(element) == 1:
            element = 0
```

But printing this is just print a copy of the original list.

How do I toggle them? Is there a function for that?
I am on Python 3.8.

Comment: Since you are speaking about *toggling*, if you are fine with having boolean values instead of string/integers, you could use `element = not element`. But pay attention that `not 0` equals `not False` equals `True`, but `not '0'` equals `False` because it is a non-empty string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`element` is a variable that holds a value from list, it doesn't "remember" where it came from, and as you've seen, overwriting it doesn't affect the list. Instead, you could iterate over the list's indexes, and update the list using the subscript (`[]`) operator:

```
for ind in range(len(check_var_list)):
    if int(check_var_list[ind]) == 0:
        check_var_list[ind] = 1
    elif int(check_var_list[ind]) == 1:
        check_var_list[ind] = 0
```

Comment: The real list consist of string value not int. So it should be `check_var_list[i] = '1'`

Comment: @Shadowcodder the OP's snippet used `0` and `1`, so I kept that behavior. Although after reading it again, I'm not sure if that was intentional

Comment: Oh, so that means `element` is an independent variable of elements in `check_var_list`, that temporarily stores a value. After the loop for that element in  `check_var_list` is over, `element` stops to hold that value and switches to the next one. Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

Try using list comprehensions instead of the above method

```
i = input('Enter something: ')
check_var_list = ['1', '1', '0']
if i == 'Particular input':
   check_var_list = ['1', '1', '0']
   check_var_list[:]=['0' if int(x)==1 else '1' for x in check_var_list]
print(check_var_list)
```

Comment: Very nicely comprehended! But in `check_var_list[:]=['0' if int(x)==1 else '1' for x in check_var_list]`, is it necessary to use `[:]`?

Comment: If its not used a new variable named `check_var_list ` is created and the values are added to that.`[;]` is used to overwrite the same variable rather than creating a new variable.

Comment: Happy to help ;)

Answer (score 1):

**First** Strings and Integers aren't intended for this purpose. Instead use `True` and `False`. Think of `True` as 1 and `False` as 0.

**Second** Doing `element = 1` does nothing but reassign element to 1. Instead, I would eliminate the for loop entirely. Do something like this:

```py
if i == 'abc':
    check_var_list = [not i for i in check_var_list]
```

You see, using the `not` keyword lets you get the reverse of a boolean, so `not True` gives `False`. This fixes your first problem. Your second problem is that you aren't reassigning your values. This solution uses list comprehension which loops over the original list, flipping the values, and then reassigning `check_var_list` to this new list.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is when you do

```
for k in list:
```

Python assigns each element of the list to the name “k”. But, “k” is just some temporary name for the element. It isn’t the element itself.

The actual list element doesn’t get modified; it just loses its name, and the updated value takes over. Try doing it via indices like

```
i = input('Enter something: ')
check_var_list = ['1', '1', '0']
if i == 'Particular input':
    for j in range(len(check_var_list)):
        if int(check_var_list[j]) == 0:
            check_var_list[j] = 1
        elif int(check_var_list[j]) == 1:
            check_var_list[j] = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no function for toggling values in python, but it is possible to write one. I would do something like this:

```
def toggle_element(element: str) -> int:
    if element == "0":
        return 1
    elif element == "1":
        return 0
    else:
        raise ValueError("Element value is not '0' or '1'.")


i = input('Enter something: ')
check_var_list = ['1', '1', '0']
if i == 'Particular input':
    check_var_list = [toggle_element(element=el) for el in check_var_list]
```